# Laravel-5 render template to string without parsing variables

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need to render a template into a string so that it can be stored in the database.

I know I can use `View::make('emails.bookingthankyou')->render()`, however this function wants to parse the variables inside my template.

I am creating a database seeder file and it needs to get the raw template and insert into the database without parsing the variables.

Is this possible?

Comment: What you want is contradictive. Rendering means parsing variables.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to find a solution.  I was able to use the render method to load my email template into a string, like so:

`View::make('emails.bookingthankyou')->render()`

I then placed @ before the curly braces in my email template and it worked just as I needed.

```
<html>
    @{{ $variable }}
</html>
```

Comment: When you retrieve that view from the database, do you somehow want to use it to populate that variable using blade? Also, there is a serious code smell to your design.

Comment: I wanted to display the contents of a `template` to a user and this worked perfectly for me. :) +1